# What is the near plane equation in NDC?

Tags: opengl, transformation, frustum

I'm trying to compute the line intersecting my plane (transformed to NDC) and the near plane.
I have troubles to get a correct result and I think it is coming from the near plane equation.

I suppose that the equation in normalized device coordinates is \$N=(0,0,1)\$ and \$O=(0,0,near)\$.
But what is the value of \$near\$? Is it constant or it depends on the frustum?

Comment: doesn't it go from -1 to 1? I thought NDC is a box that goes from -1 to 1 on all axis

Comment: @Sidar, yes you're right. I managed to fix my issue, thanks. The equation of near plane in NDC is \$z+1=0\$

Comment: might want to post the answer then =P

Answer (score 3):

In NDC, the clipping planes are a box that goes from -1 to 1.
Near plane equation is therefore \$Z+1=0\$ and far plane \$Z-1=0\$